# Chromosome data storage for a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary

I am making a GA simulation and I struggle to find a method to read and write a color value into the Chromosome of each solution. Currently I am using a simple array with three indexes and just storing them as an int, but this seems inefficient and I have read that most prefer binary for it's ease in crossover.

How can I read and write this information into a binary string?

Comment: [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369920/genetic-algorithm-binary-encoding) it may be a little bit of help.

Comment: Which is the range of each value ?

Comment: 100-255 or 0.4 - 1.0 Either will work.